# Unable to use my built-in SD card reader - Dell Precision 3571 - Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, 22.04, sd-card

The SD cards are working fine on another Linux machine, but does not work into mine. I can't mount one formated in EXT4. Another in nfts can be mounted but is unusable.
I suspect a problem with my SD card reader, hardware or a driver issue :

```
$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu-pgr 6.0.0-1008-oem #8-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Nov 16 17:31:27 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lshw
ubuntu-pgr                  
    description: Notebook
    product: Precision 3571 (0B10)
    vendor: Dell Inc.
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-3.4.0 dmi-3.4.0 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=notebook family=Precision sku=0B10
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       vendor: Dell Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: A00
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: Dell Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: 1.6.0
          date: 07/07/2022
          size: 1MiB
          capacity: 32MiB
          capabilities: pci pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb smartbattery biosbootspecification netboot uefi
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-12600H
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 400
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: 6.154.3
          slot: U3E1
          size: 3200MHz
          capacity: 4500MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
(...)
*-pci:5
     description: PCI bridge
     product: Intel Corporation
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 1d
     bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
     version: 01
     width: 32 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
     configuration: driver=pcieport
     resources: irq:127 memory:8f000000-8f0fffff
   *-generic
        description: MMC Host
        product: GL9755 SD Host Controller
        vendor: Genesys Logic, Inc
        physical id: 0
        bus info: pci@0000:74:00.0
        logical name: mmc0
        version: 01
        width: 32 bits
        clock: 33MHz
        capabilities: pciexpress msi pm bus_master cap_list
        configuration: driver=sdhci-pci latency=0
        resources: irq:133 memory:8f000000-8f000fff
        
$ dmesg
[ 1811.033050] mmc0: new ultra high speed SDR104 SDHC card at address 0001
[ 1811.038878] mmcblk0: mmc0:0001 SD 7.44 GiB 
[ 1811.040127]  mmcblk0: p1 p2
[ 1819.449754] sdb: detected capacity change from 1072 to 0
[ 1819.856511] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 270337 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[ 1819.856518] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0p1, logical block 0, lost sync page write
[ 1819.856530] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p1): I/O error while writing superblock
[ 1819.856541] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p1): mount failed
[ 1823.447060] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounting ext2 file system using the ext4 subsystem
[ 1823.451863] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): __ext4_fill_super:5227: inode #2: comm pool-udisksd: iget: bad extended attribute block 4294901760
[ 1823.486987] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 262144 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[ 1823.486994] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0p2, logical block 0, lost sync page write
[ 1823.487020] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): I/O error while writing superblock
[ 1823.487043] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): Remounting filesystem read-only
[ 1823.487051] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): get root inode failed
[ 1823.487052] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mount failed
[ 1853.016864] mmc0: card 0001 removed

# With manual mounting : mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /media/SDCARD/
[  700.905362] mmc0: new ultra high speed SDR104 SDHC card at address 0001
[  700.905848] mmcblk0: mmc0:0001 SD 7.44 GiB 
[  700.907252]  mmcblk0: p1
[  715.048836] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 1048576 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  715.048848] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0p1, logical block 0, lost sync page write
[  715.048977] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p1): I/O error while writing superblock
[  715.048992] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p1): mount failed
[  835.833583] mmc0: Tuning failed, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[  905.619506] mmc0: Card is consuming too much power!

# Another SD CARD with NTFS:
[ 5476.864610] mmc0: new ultra high speed SDR104 SDHC card at address 5048
[ 5476.865003] mmcblk0: mmc0:5048 SD32G 29.7 GiB 
[ 5476.865782]  mmcblk0: p1
[ 5481.958739] ntfs3: Max link count 4000
[ 5481.958742] ntfs3: Enabled Linux POSIX ACLs support
[ 5481.958742] ntfs3: Read-only LZX/Xpress compression included
[ 5481.958956] ntfs3: Unknown parameter 'windows_names'
[ 5482.678477] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 34689693 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 4 prio class 2
[ 5482.680881] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 34689701 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 3 prio class 2
[ 5482.681777] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 34689704 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 2 prio class 2
[ 5482.740118] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 34689709 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 2 prio class 2
[ 5482.741329] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 34689711 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 2 prio class 2
[ 5482.796131] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 34689713 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[ 5482.798451] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 34689719 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[ 5483.515547] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 34689727 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 16 prio class 2
[ 5483.519471] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 34689744 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 13 prio class 2
[ 5483.520728] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 34689750 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 13 prio class 2
[ 5487.613022] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0p1, logical block 974213, lost async page write
[ 5487.613123] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0p1, logical block 5, lost async page write
[ 5631.027313] blk_print_req_error: 19 callbacks suppressed
[ 5631.027316] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 62356824 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[ 5633.041217] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 24 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[ 5633.357400] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 24 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[ 5633.357407] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0, logical block 3, async page read
[ 5634.437244] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 62356528 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[ 5635.511765] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 62357376 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[ 5635.512494] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 62357376 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[ 5635.512496] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0, logical block 7794672, async page read
[ 5674.257502] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 139377 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 8 prio class 2
[ 5674.264498] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 139406 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 5 prio class 2
[ 5674.273301] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 139408 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 4 prio class 2
[ 5674.273873] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 139410 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 4 prio class 2
[ 5674.274266] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 139412 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 4 prio class 2
[ 5674.276866] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 139424 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 2 prio class 2
[ 5674.277939] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 139428 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 2 prio class 2
[ 5674.278260] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 139429 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 2 prio class 2
[ 5674.278649] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 139431 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 2 prio class 2
[ 5674.279290] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 139433 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[ 5678.073329] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0p1, logical block 974213, lost async page write
[ 5678.190023] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0p1, logical block 5, lost async page write
[ 5678.245038] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0p1, logical block 16393, lost async page write
[ 5678.245167] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0p1, logical block 10724, lost async page write
[ 5679.196083] usb 4-3: USB disconnect, device number 2
[ 5679.807483] blk_print_req_error: 12 callbacks suppressed
[ 5679.807485] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 8465 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 29 prio class 2
[ 5679.808339] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 8469 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 29 prio class 2
[ 5679.808605] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 8470 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 29 prio class 2
[ 5679.812629] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 8490 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 26 prio class 2
[ 5679.825988] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 8512 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 23 prio class 2
[ 5679.826624] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 8514 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 23 prio class 2
[ 5679.827236] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 8517 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 23 prio class 2
[ 5679.827449] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 8518 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 23 prio class 2
[ 5679.828509] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 8522 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 22 prio class 2
[ 5679.830270] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 8528 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 21 prio class 2
[ 5680.688421] mmc0: tried to HW reset card, got error -110
[ 5680.697466] mmcblk0: recovery failed!
[ 5680.706332] mmcblk0: recovery failed!
[ 5680.706335] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0p1, logical block 7793649, async page read
[ 5680.715131] mmcblk0: recovery failed!
[ 5680.723859] mmcblk0: recovery failed!
[ 5680.723863] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0, logical block 0, async page read
[ 5680.731502] mmcblk0: recovery failed!
[ 5680.731504] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0, logical block 0, async page read
[ 5680.739132] mmcblk0: recovery failed!
[ 5680.739133] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0, logical block 0, async page read
[ 5680.746799] mmcblk0: recovery failed!
[ 5680.746800] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0, logical block 0, async page read
[ 5680.754454] mmcblk0: recovery failed!
[ 5680.754455] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0, logical block 0, async page read
[ 5681.756256] mmc0: card 5048 removed
[ 5683.168086] mmc0: new ultra high speed SDR104 SDHC card at address 5048
[ 5683.168452] mmcblk0: mmc0:5048 SD32G 29.7 GiB 
[ 5683.169633]  mmcblk0: p1
[ 5692.172661] mmc0: card 5048 removed
[ 5694.936052] mmc0: new ultra high speed SDR104 SDHC card at address 5048
[ 5694.936253] mmcblk0: mmc0:5048 SD32G 29.7 GiB 
[ 5694.937216]  mmcblk0: p1
[ 5695.897462] blk_print_req_error: 19 callbacks suppressed
[ 5695.897464] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 62356824 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[ 5696.513092] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 10240 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[ 5697.171417] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 8724 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 62 prio class 2
[ 5697.175902] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 8745 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 59 prio class 2
[ 5697.176101] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 8746 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 59 prio class 2
[ 5697.181314] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 8768 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 56 prio class 2
[ 5697.185795] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 8786 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 54 prio class 2
[ 5697.186062] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 8787 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 54 prio class 2
[ 5697.186327] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 8788 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 54 prio class 2
[ 5697.186695] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 8789 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 54 prio class 2
[ 5697.828235] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0p1, logical block 72, async page read
[ 5705.296619] mmc0: card 5048 removed
[ 5762.516138] mmc0: new ultra high speed SDR104 SDHC card at address 5048
[ 5762.516561] mmcblk0: mmc0:5048 SD32G 29.7 GiB 
[ 5762.517737]  mmcblk0: p1
[ 5762.976087] blk_print_req_error: 29 callbacks suppressed
[ 5762.976089] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 62356772 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[ 5763.922406] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 62356518 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
```

Comment: A relatively simple way to check whether it's a driver or hardware issue would be to boot into a Live Session using your Ubuntu installation USB. If the SD cards are readable in the Live Session, then there's something that needs to be fixed with your installation. If it still doesn't work, then it *may* point to hardware issues 

Comment: I tested that with a ubuntu 20.04 and manjaro 21.05 image. In both cases I was not able to mount the partition.